# What is causing 'I/PhenotypeProcessReaper: Memory state is: 100' message in Android Studio console?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, memory, terminal

I'm getting the following message on my android studio console.

`I/PhenotypeProcessReaper(12917): Memory state is: 100`

If you know the reason, kindly elaborate this. Thanks in Advance.

I think so it is because of SingleTickerProviderStateMixin. Agreed?